# Kivy (Python) a scrollable view, inside the view a group of buttons (can be multiplied) standing at the bottom of the window instead of top

Tags: python, kivy, scrollview

I have a Python code running a Kivy interface. In the interface, there is a section where I have a filter group (a group of buttons, spinners, text input box) standing horizontally. This filter group can be multiplied (under the initial filter group) by the user as much as the user wants. That's why this section is inside a scrollable view.

However, when running the code, the initial filter group is standing at the bottom of the view. Once multiply the filter group you can't see the newly created filters (because they are created under the initial one and since the initial one is at the bottom of the window, the new ones are out of the window) unless you scroll the view up.

So in terms of functionality, everything works just fine.

The only problem is visual; the initial filter group is standing at the bottom of the view and there is white space above it.

The question is: How can I move the filter group to the top of the view?

Below is the Kivy code:

```
ScrollView:
    id: sv
    do_scroll_x: False

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        size_hint_y: None
        height: max(self.minimum_height, sv.height)
        padding: 5

        BoxLayout:
            #spacing: 2
            size_hint_y: None
            height: max(self.minimum_height, sv.height)
            padding: 5

            Label:
                text: "1"
                size_hint_x: 0.1
                size_hint_y: 0.25

            Spinner:
                text: "2"
                values: ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
                size_hint_x: 0.2
                size_hint_y: 0.25

            Spinner:
                text: "3"
                values: ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
                size_hint_x: 0.2
                size_hint_y: 0.25

            Spinner:
                text: "4"
                values: ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
                size_hint_x: 0.2
                size_hint_y: 0.25

            TextInput:
                hint_text: "5"
                size_hint_x: 0.2
                size_hint_y: 0.25

            Button:
                text: "+"
                size_hint_x: 0.1
                size_hint_y: 0.25`
```

Under ScrollView there is a GridLayout. I changed it to BoxLayout and the orientation to vertical.
I also tried pos_hint under scroll view or a grid layout or box layout (just in case I tried all)
Again functionality is ok but the visual is still the same.

[The snapshot shows that the filter group is at the bottom. And I want the filter group to stand at the top of the view on the initial run.]

[image]

[And this is as a gif]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
height: max(self.minimum_height, sv.height)
```

is part of the problem. You can just use the simpler:

```
height: self.minimum_height
```

in two places. But whenever you use `self.minimum_height`, the contents of that `Layout` must have defined heights. So each `Button`, `Label`, `Spinner`, and `TextInput` must have explicit heights. So here is a modified version of your Kivy code:

```
ScrollView:
    id: sv
    do_scroll_x: False

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        size_hint_y: None
        # height: max(self.minimum_height, sv.height)
        height: self.minimum_height
        padding: 5

        BoxLayout:
            #spacing: 2
            size_hint_y: None
            # height: max(self.minimum_height, sv.height)
            height: self.minimum_height
            padding: 5

            Label:
                text: "1"
                size_hint_x: 0.1
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 30

            Spinner:
                text: "2"
                values: ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
                size_hint_x: 0.2
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 30

            Spinner:
                text: "3"
                values: ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
                size_hint_x: 0.2
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 30

            Spinner:
                text: "4"
                values: ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
                size_hint_x: 0.2
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 30

            TextInput:
                hint_text: "5"
                size_hint_x: 0.2
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 30

            Button:
                text: "+"
                size_hint_x: 0.1
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 30
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried your solution and it worked however buttons become somehow un-clickable. [link](https://imgur.com/a/RK3QzdA) _italic_ **bold**

Comment: Your gif in the link does not look like what I get. Did you copy my solution exactly? Perhaps there is something in your code that you did not post.

Comment: When you indicated `height: self.minimum_height`, i paid attention there only, sorry. The other difference between your code and my code was: I used `size_hint_y: 0.25` while you used `size_hint_y: None` & `height: 30`. Now its better, thank you